# Puppeteer async function that works but raises error in test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, puppeteer

I'm trying to test an async function using Chai.js. It works when I call it from the program but it returns undefined when it comes to testing.

This is the function

```
async function getLinks(url, minW = 1, minH = 1) {
  try {
    const pup = await puppeteer.launch({ defaultViewport: null });
    let page = await pup.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    return await page.evaluate(
      ({ minW, minH }) => {
        return [...document.getElementsByTagName('a')]
          .map(x => {
            return { url: x.href, type: 'a' };
          })
          .concat(
            [...document.getElementsByTagName('img')]
              .filter(x => x.naturalWidth >= minW && x.naturalHeight >= minH)
              .map(x => {
                return { url: x.src, type: 'img' };
              })
          );
      },
      { minW, minH }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This is the test

```
describe('getLinks', () => {
    it('should return an array of links.', async function() {
      const links = await getLinks('http://www.msftconnecttest.com');
      expect(links).to.be.an('array');
    }).timeout(5000);
  });
```

and, here is the error I get

```
1) getLinks
       should return an array of links.:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to be an array
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\test.js:9:27)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
```

**UPDATE**:
The code is falling into the catch block and here is the original error message:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_1xrphtbyiu is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:18
      at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
      at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:48:12)
      at async getLinks (main.js:1:6360)
      at async Context.<anonymous> (test\test.js:8:21)
```

Comment: Maybe it's falling into the `catch` block? There you are returning nothing.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm gonna update the question.

Comment: Are you running this through webpack or some transpiler?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher No, I run it directly with neither transpilers nor bundlers.

Comment: "cov_1xrphtbyiu" is so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason that it became problematic because I don't use Babel or similar tools but after I changed the `return` to blow code and now it works both in test and program.

It might be a version-specific problem.

```js
return await page.evaluate(
      `((minW, minH) => {
        return [...document.getElementsByTagName('a')]
          .map(x => {
            return { url: x.href, type: 'a' };
          })
          .concat(
            [...document.getElementsByTagName('img')]
              .filter(x => x.naturalWidth >= minW && x.naturalHeight >= minH)
              .map(x => {
                return { url: x.src, type: 'img' };
              })
          );
      })(${minW}, ${minH})`,
    );
```